# python: Trying to add another "timered" print function inside a loop, with not great success :D

Tags: python, loops, timer

First part was cut.. Sorry to ask this but I'm new to python and programming in general. My knowledge and experience is lacking and I'm not always able to find (or understand) what I need to do to achieve something.

Right now I'm performing  `print('2')` every 2 secs, and `print('30')` every 30secs.

So right now I would like to implement another function `print('10')`  to perform every  10 secs, within the loop.

Can you help me understand how to achieve this?

```
SHORT_DELAY = 2
LONG_DELAY = 30 

accum_time = LONG_DELAY

while True: 
    print('2') 
    if accum_time > LONG_DELAY: 
        print('30')
        accum_time -= LONG_DELAY

    time.sleep(SHORT_DELAY) 
    accum_time += SHORT_DELAY
```

Wo, what to do now??
To achieve my goal I would say I need to set another var, for example  `MID_DELAY = 10`, but then how can I implement this new parameter in the loop?
I can't solve this simple task because if I'm resetting the `mid_delay` I will never get the `long_delay` value to be bigger than 30, and if I reset the `long_delay` the `mid_delay` would actually works ONLY after the `long_delay` has been resetted, so it would print "10" only after the 30 seconds have been resetted.
Also with the code like this I get a "30" print results after few seconds. (I think that's because the loop starts with `accum_time` already with a value of "30", and so as soon as it get bigger it prints)

Hope my question is clear.
Sorry if there is confusion, I was trying to "debug" as writing this, still with no success..
Forgive me I'm noob.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not necessary to use "for" loop in your problem. Start thinking "How to resolve my problem?" What do you want to do?
You want to print something at appropriate intervals. And you want to set this intervals in your variables.
So start timing and check that the values ​​have been reached with function IF

```
import time

SHORT_DELAY = 2
MID_DELAY = 10
LONG_DELAY = 30
accum_time = 0

    while True:
        if accum_time == 0:
            pass
        elif accum_time % LONG_DELAY == 0:
            print('30')
        elif accum_time % MID_DELAY == 0:
            print('10')
        else accum_time % SHORT_DELAY == 0:
            print('2')

    time.sleep(SHORT_DELAY)
    accum_time += SHORT_DELAY
```

Of course while accum_time is increasing by SHORT_DELAY you don't have to check statement in "else".

```
else:
    print('2')
```

Answer (score 0):

I can help you,
I changed the code a bit so its easier to read for me.

```
import time

SHORT_DELAY = 2

while True: 
    print('2')
    SHORT_DELAY += 1
    time.sleep(2)
#when 30 seconds is full it prints 30
    if SHORT_DELAY==31:
        SHORT_DELAY=0
        print('30')
when 10 seconds is full it prints 10
    if SHORT_DELAY==11 or 21 or 31:
        print('10')
```

I hope I helped. Message me if something is wrong or hard to understand.